# Powermock verifyPrivate does not work with any()

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I have a private method whose invocation I want to test without caring about the arguments. I want to test if it was called at all or not.

MyClass.java

```
public void doStuff(){
    unload(args);
}

private void unload(List<String> args) {
    // 
}
```

So I used following:

MyClasstest.java

```
MyClass myClass = PowerMockito.spy(new MyClass());
myClass.doStuff();
verifyPrivate(myClass, times(1)).invoke("unload",any(List.class));
//     verifyPrivate(myClass, times(1)).invoke("unload",any());  //same result with this
```

This test fails with following exception:

> Wanted but not invoked com.MyClass.unload(
>       null );
>
> However, there were other interactions with this mock  ....... 
>   (actual values with which it was called)

Can verifyPrivate be called with only actual arguments & not with `any()`?

Comment: [`any(Class)`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#any-java.lang.Class-) does not match `null`. You will have to use [`any()`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#any--) instead.

Comment: @second getting same error with `any()`

Comment: Could you show the whole stacktrace?

Comment: If you can convert the example into an [mre] it would be easier to figure it out. What is `args` in your example?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example of what you are trying to do:

You might just missing the `@PrepareForTest` annotation, which has to point to the correct class. If your class is an external one use `@PrepareForTest(MyClass.class)`, the example below shows it with an internal class.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyClassTest.class)
public class MyClassTest {

    static class MyClass {

        public void doStuff(){
            unload(null);
        }

        private void unload(List<String> args) {
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        MyClass myClass = PowerMockito.spy(new MyClass());
        myClass.doStuff();
        PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(myClass, Mockito.times(1)).invoke("unload", Mockito.any());
    }
}
```

---

Note that you should consider whether you really want to do this in a UnitTest. Normally your UnitTest should not be concerned about whether a `private` method is used or not, it should be focused on verifying that the correct result is returned or the correct object state is reached.

By adding knowledge about the internal behaviour of the class into it, you test is tightly coupled to the implementation which might not be a good thing.